# Use mb_chars on simple_form RUBY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm using the gem simple_form and trying to do a ".mb_chars" on my field. Any idea?
My field:

```
<%= f.input :metadesc_mb, label: 'Meta description' %>
```

Maybe something like this (don't work):

```
<%= f.input :metadesc_mb.mb_chars, label: 'Meta description' %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should use `:value_method` key to pass the string processed with `#mb_chars`. That will 
something like the following:

```
<%= f.input :metadesc_mb, label: 'Meta description', value_method: -> { self.metadesc_mb.mb_chars } -%>
```

or to use `:value` subkey of `:input_html` key:

```
<%= f.input :metadesc_mb, label: 'Meta description', input_html: { value: self.metadesc_mb.mb_chars } -%>
```

**NOTE**: The last method can't be applied to collections.